Creating a Disjoint Sets Data Structure Diagram in TikZ
I'm currently studying the CLRS textbook on algorithms and I've come across a figure representing disjoint sets as a collection of trees, where each tree represents a set. I'm looking to recreate a diagram similar to the one in the attached image using TikZ for inclusion in my LaTeX notes.
The image depicts various nodes with letter labels and a numerical subscript, and arrows indicating the parent in the tree of disjoint sets.
I'm fairly new to TikZ and am struggling to get started on how to best represent these structures. Could anyone provide a simple example or template of TikZ code that could generate a similar diagram? Specifically, any tips on how to manage the positioning of nodes and the directed edges would be highly valuable.
Attached is the image I am referring to.

I appreciate any guidance you can provide!

Search for automata made with TikZ.

Picking the automata idea: have a look here: https://tikz.dev/library-automata

Here's some  kind of starter for you, but please provide code next time.
(A) In general I suggest to execute a process like this:

place nodes
introduce styles
draw connections
do refinements

(B) There are several ways to place nodes, like:

absolute (below)
using polar coordinates (below)
tikzlibrary positioning
tikz matrix (of nodes)
etc. i.e. make your choice

Tree or forest may be not the best approach here for a beginner.
(C) By intention I left out one nodes style to demonstrate both the effect and the process.
(D) Connecting is rather straight forward, and you place no tip, a tip at one side, or at both. Make your choice.
There are several ways to create a self-loop. I combined:

using an intermediate point (in relative coordinates)
replacing -- by to[out=,in=] for better control.

(E) So now you have everything available to finish the whole diagram on your own. Remember, using the pgfmanual and searching this site can save you a lot of trouble.

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
% ~~~ 4. have nicer arrow tips ~~~~~~~~
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    % ~~~ 2. introduce and use styles ~~~~~~
    circ/.style={draw,circle},
    % ~~~ 4. have nicer arrow tips ~~~~~~~~
    >={Stealth},
    ]
    % ~~~ 1. place nodes as needed ~~~~~
    \node[circ] (h1) at (0,0)   {h,1};  
    \node[circ] (e0) at (-40:2) {e,0};  
    \node       (g2) at (210:2) {g,2};  % for demo purposes
    
    % ~~~ placement more or less ok? ~~~
    
    % ~~~ 3. draw some connections ~~~~
    \draw[->] (e0) -- (h1);
    \draw[<-] (g2) -- (h1); % if you prefer opposite direction
    \draw[->] (g2) to[out=150,in=90] +(-1,0) to[out=270,in=220] (g2);
    
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

